# Async & Await in C#: Do I have to change the entire Call Chain Up to a Void Method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm completely new to this whole Async / Await topic on C#. Despite countless questions being answered and tutorials [being linked to relentlessly](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), I still seem to be unable to wrap my head around how to use async/await. All I want to achieve is the wpf application to return to rendering animations on the UI while it waits for an expensive method call to finish - in my following example, that'd be `GetLinesAsync()`, or more specifically, `expensive_function()` within:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show(GetAMessage());
}

string GetAMessage() {
    string ret = "";
    foreach(string s in GetLinesAsync().Result)
        ret += $"{s}\n";
    return ret;
}

async Task<List<string>> GetLinesAsync() {
    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    string[] ExpensiveResult = null;
    if (await Task.Run(() => expensive_function(ref ExpensiveResult)) == expensive_stat.SUCCESS && ExpensiveResult != null)
    {
        foreach(string s in ExpensiveResult)
            ret.Add(s);
    }
```

Written like that, the application freezes completely, even though `expensive_function()` doesn't take THAT long to perform. Besides that I'm not sure why this happens, here's what I've understood from reading tutorials and explanations on await/async, especially the part saying you can only await methods that return either void or Task:

The line `foreach(string s in GetLinesAsync().Result)` should actually say `foreach(string s in await GetLinesAsync().Result)` - but then I'd have to mark `GetMessages()` async, and then I'd have to replace `MessageBox.Show(GetAMessage())` with `MessageBox.Show(await GetMessages())` and mark `Button_Click()` async.

In other words: the awaitability would creep up the call stack until it reaches a void method. Okay, but that can't be it, can it? What if, in some other scenario, there is no senseful void method to creep up to, even?

Comment: `In other words: the awaitability would creep up the call stack until it reaches a void method` yes, this is what happens, and how it works in the real world. let it propagate, don't hold it back

Comment: It isn't *always* a `void` method at the root though.  C# 7 introduced [`async main`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/), which allows you to have a `public static async Task Main(string[] args)` method as the entry point for your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you code is blocking, is because you block it here.

```
foreach(string s in GetLinesAsync().Result)
```

You are saying *UI thread* wait until my expensive task has finished

Just let `asyn`c flow free.

- In Windows Forms and WPF, `async`/`await` has the handy property of coming back to the UI thread when the asynchronous operation you were awaiting has completed
- Support for `async` on a void method was added specifically to support event handlers. however make sure you handle your exceptions as void will be unobserved

So you could just do this.

**Note** : this is an extremely simplified and sanitized example based on your code

```
public async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      MessageBox.Show(await GetAMessage());
   }
   catch (Exception exception)
   {
      // log the nelly out of it
      // or display message
   }

}

public async Task<string> GetAMessage()
{
   var list = await GetLinesAsync();

   return string.Join("\n", list);
}

public List<string> ExpensiveFunction()
{
   // ...
   return new List<string>();
}


public async Task<List<string>> GetLinesAsync()
{
   var result = Task.Run(() => ExpensiveFunction());
   return await result;
}
```

Comment: That's also what Microsoft says in their article [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) - which is fine for void-returning event handlers such as `Button_Click()`. Is there another way where I define a callback, saying "Run `expensive_function()` in a separate task, continue, and run `callback()` when you're done"?

Comment: @draconigen If you dont want to not use async awat, just smash off a `task` or a `thread`, and marshal back to the ui thread when you want to show your message or update the ui. `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: sorry, my remark seems misleading. What I meant is: is there a way with async/await to name a callback function with parameters and ask for it to be run after task completion?

Comment: Yeah an action will do just this. I mean create an `Action<type,type,..>` in your main class, and just call that when you want to notify , research `Action<T>` and this should get you out of trouble, its like an event

Comment: Actions look like the thing I was searching for! That and "async all the way up", should cover all scenarios, thanks!